# Show notice just below the search form on the themes page

Tags: theme-development, hooks, core

I want to show a notice on the theme installation page. I have used the `admin_notices` hook but it is showing the message above the search box.
[image: Add notice]
I want to print the notice at the place of a black line in the image.

For the plugin page, we have the `pre_current_active_plugins` hook but for the themes page, I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no hook available to place a notice in the spot you've pointed out.

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/themes.php#L262), you can see that the "New theme activated" message is one of several hard-coded messages, and no filter or action exists to add a custom message.

If you *really* wanted to, you could add your message using the `admin_notices` hook, then use some JS to move it to the desired location, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's probably best to just go with the flow, and use `admin_notices`.